# StreamChannel don't send continuous data to flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

Im trying to set a continuos broadcast from Kotlin to dart using an EventChannel, following this example: [GITHUB REPO](https://github.com/Destiny-Ed/Flutter-Event-Channel) it uses an IntentFilter in order to notify the battery status.

What im trying to do is to return each second if possible a value that's stored on a sharedPreference, but it doesn't matter if I set the Intent to stream with action_send, flutter doesn't receive the value.

this is the current code.

```
private lateinit var streamChannel: EventChannel
private lateinit var statusValueStateChangeReceiver: BroadcastReceiver

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {

      streamChannel = EventChannel(
            flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "continuous.stream.boolean/statusValue")

        streamChannel.setStreamHandler(this)

    }


    
override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink?) {
        statusValueStateChangeReceiver = createStatusValueStateChangeReceiver(events);
        applicationContext.registerReceiver(
            statusValueStateChangeReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SEND));
    }

    override fun onCancel(arguments: Any?) {
        applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(statusValueStateChangeReceiver);
    }

    private fun createStatusValueStateChangeReceiver(events: EventChannel.EventSink?): BroadcastReceiver {
        return object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                events?.success(intent?.let { MyClass().getStatusValue() })
            }
        }
    }
```

how can I keep sending the data to dart in a persistent way? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep, if i change the IntentFilter param with the battery status as the example on github i receive the data

Comment: Is a static method: MyClass().getStatusValue() tha returns a true or false, however the data can changes on any time, and that's why i need a continuous listener :(